# adb reboot command hangs emulator Options

Tags: android, build, emulation, dalvik, reboot

I want to make newly built file libdvm.so (after making few changes to vm code). I have got the file after the build.I pushed the file into emulator using

```
$ adb push libdvm.so /system/lib/libdvm.so
```

And since for changes to take place i tried to reboot using

```
$adb reboot
```

But this is making the emulator to hang up. Any solution or suggestion to this problem? I have also tried earlier android versions but result is same.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building dalvik from scratch, why not just build the emulator and generic emulator system image while you are at it?

```
cd <android_source>
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch full-eng
make -j4
out/host/linux-x86/bin/emulator
```

Comment: I have tried ur procedure and build was successful but when i start the emulator and do a $adb shell and when the checked the properties of libdvm.so file in /system/lib using ls -l it gave this output        -rw-r--r-- root     root       753908 2011-12-14 05:41 libdvm.so
Doesn't the date of creation for libdvm.so file be today's date(date  of build)?